# Load XML into mxml (Flex AS3)

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am trying to display content of an xml file in a textarea (using Flex 4.7).
But I am getting errors and I am not sure why.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->         
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            
            var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML); // 1st error here
            xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("books.xml")); // 2nd error here
            
            var xmlData:XML = new XML();
            
            function loadXML(e:Event):void{             
                xmlData = new XML (e.target.data);              
            }               
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    
    <s:VGroup>      
        <s:TextArea id="txtArea">       
        </s:TextArea>               
    </s:VGroup>
    
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Here are my errors:

> Multiple markets at this line:
>
> -1120: Access of undefined propertyloadXML (1st error)
>
> -1120: Access of undefined property xmlLoader (2nd error)

This is the app structure:

> Tester
>
> - src
>
> -- (default package)
>
> --- Tester.mxml
>
> -- books.xml
>
> -- Tester-app.xml

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Could anyone please get me on the right track?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your ActionScript code must go inside a method; and you have code that must be put in a method.  Variable definitions are okay.  Import statements are okay.  I think some directives, such as include are okay. But, other code must be in a method.

This is your annotated code:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        // this is a variable definition so it is good
        var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

        // these two lines are code that executes; so they must be put inside a method; something you did not do.  Comment them out 
        //xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML); // 1st error here
        //xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("books.xml")); // 2nd error here

        // this is a variable definition so it is okay
        var xmlData:XML = new XML();

        // this is a function definition so it is okay
        function loadXML(e:Event):void{             
            xmlData = new XML (e.target.data);              
        }               

        // move your executing code into a method
        public function load():void{
         xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);
         xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("books.xml"));
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

I bet that removes your errors.  However, you'll also want to / need to do something to execute that load method.  When you do this depends on how the data is used in your app and the current component.  But, I'd probably add a preinitialize event listener:

```
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                       preinitialize="load()">
```

If preinitialize doesn't work; I'd move the code to the initialize event.  If that doesn't work; I'd go to the creationComplete event.

Comment: Thanks so much Reboog711! Worked like a charm.